# Ignore scrollbar width for container in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a fixed navigation menu at the top of the page with the same width as the other containers. I can't figure out why the nav container ignores the width of the scrollbar. I don't want to permanently enable the bar and I'm afraid adding margins will look weird on different sized viewports.
Here is the code:

```css
:root {
    --foreground-color: grey;
}

header {
    background-color: var(--foreground-color);
}

nav {
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em 0% 1em 0%;
    justify-content: right;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 10% 10%;
    border-bottom: solid;
}

.navlink {
    background-color: dimgrey;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black, darkolivegreen);
}

.title{
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    
}

main {
    background-color: var(--foreground-color);
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.center-content-x{
    position: fixed;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav>
            <a class="navlink" href="index.html" name="Home">Home</a>
            <a class="navlink" href="about.html" name="About">About</a>
            <a class="navlink" href="gallery.html" name="Gallery">Gallery</a>
            <a class="navlink" href="contact.html" name="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Sierra Custom Doors</h1>
            <p>"Your Reputation Is In Our Doors"</p>
        </div>


    </header>
```

I know it's very sloppy but, I'm fairly new to this. Any other criticism would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly but try this

```
nav {
background-color: grey;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
width: calc(100% - 16px); /* <----- THIS LINE */
padding: 1em 0% 1em 0%;
justify-content: right;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 10% 10%;
border-bottom: solid;}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I wanted. I have not used calc() in a css sheet before so this is extremely helpful.

Comment: this answer assumes that: 1. scrollbar is always presented 2. scrollbar has always 16px width.  both assumptions may not be correct on various platforms and layout situations

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```css
:root {
    --foreground-color: grey;
}

header {
    background-color: var(--foreground-color);
}

nav {
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left:0.5em;
    right:0.5em;
    padding: 1em 0% 1em 0%;
    justify-content: right;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 10% 10%;
    border-bottom: solid;
}

.navlink {
    background-color: dimgrey;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black, darkolivegreen);
}

.title{
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    
}

main {
    background-color: var(--foreground-color);
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.center-content-x{
    position: fixed;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a class="navlink" href="index.html" name="Home">Home</a>
            <a class="navlink" href="about.html" name="About">About</a>
            <a class="navlink" href="gallery.html" name="Gallery">Gallery</a>
            <a class="navlink" href="contact.html" name="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Sierra Custom Doors</h1>
            <p>"Your Reputation Is In Our Doors"</p>
        </div>


    </header>
```

For the `nav` element, `width: 100%;` has been replaced with `left: 0.5em; right: 0.5em;` (obviously, just change the values as required).